# How to float a video player over all pages like youtube in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, video-player

I want to create a video player like youtube which will appear all over the screen like youtube app.

[image: Full screen video]

After minimize or back pressed this video will play like this for all screens:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can try [miniplayer](https://pub.dev/packages/miniplayer) dependencies and read [how to persistence](https://pub.dev/packages/miniplayer#persistence) to pass miniplayer over all pages.

Answer (score 0):

Use the same controller and pass it to a new widget( the one sitting down at bottom) and use hero animation to swap it there.

Comment: I tried using Hero with video_player but it never works, did you manage to achieve that ?

Comment: Thats because the video_player widget might not be rendered beforehand ur hero widget searches for a target widget location to start animation. U have to render it before the hero animation starts.